# Expected value of the log of the sum of beta distribution

Tags: distributions, bayesian, expected-value, beta-distribution

Can someone help me compute this expression:

$$E[\log(X Y + (1-X)(1-Y))]$$
where $X\sim\operatorname{Beta}(a_1,b_1)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Beta}(a_2,b_2)$, and where $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

In the end, I want this expression to be written as a function of the parameters $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$.

Comment: It appears this problem does not have a convenient closed-form solution. Just solving the first of two required integrals yields a very complicated HypergeometricPFQ function ... which then needs to be integrated again.